# Coldfusion session management and locking variables

Tags: session-variables, coldfusion-9, application.cfc

I've been reading about locking the various persistent variables, application, session, etc.  and I understand the race conditions that exists with reading application variables that are updated often.

I'm not so sure about session variables and application variables that don't change.  I am on a single server and CF9.  I'm locking the session variables when I set them, but is it really necessary to lock them when reading them. Doesn't each user have their own set of session variables.  How would changing values for one user effect an different user viewing the same page at the same time.

Also, I set application variables in my application.cfc file and they do not change. Are locks needed every time I read the application.dsn variable?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to lock session variables unless you have part of your app that is going to be modifying the user's session directly (which is part of an undocumented feature in CF, so it's not likely you're doing that anyway).

As for Application variables, you shouldn't need to lock those either if you're just setting them once and never messing with them again.